# Undefined Indexes

Tags: codeigniter

I’m still confused on what I’m doing wrong. I keep getting undefined indexes.

Here's the `print_r`.

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [site_name] => Kansas Outlaw Wrestling 
        [site_slogan] => True Outlaws of The Midwest 
    ) 
)
```

Here’s my kow.php view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="author" content="Jeff Davidson" />
<title><?php echo $template['title']; ?></title>
<?php echo $template['metadata']; ?>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Here’s my controller:

```
$activeTemplate = $this->kow->getTemplate(); 
        $siteInfo = $this->kow->getSiteTitleAndSlogan(); 
        $this->template
        ->title($siteInfo['site_name'],$siteInfo['site_slogan'])
        ->prepend_metadata('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/assets/css/'.$activeTemplate['short_name'].'.css" />')

        ->build('kow');
        print_r($siteInfo);
```

Comment: Can you please post the actual error? (i.e. undefined index on what variable?)

Comment: try `$siteInfo->site_name`, and `$siteInfo->site_slogan`, because your referencing items in an object, not array.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for this but looking at your `print_r`, I can tell that `$siteInfo` is an array containing one object so what I think you're looking for is actually `$siteInfo[0]->site_name` and `$siteInfo[0]->site_slogan`.